# mouseEntered does not appear for JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I had this idea to build sort-of a receipt-system that shows the amount of expenses made at any time and a graph of how the expenses changed over time.   The data is saved in a MySQL database.

My Problem regards specifically the Graph part. I have built one (that has labels to show the values at that specific point) and was thinking to add a hover option that works like the following:
once the user hovers over a value, the time of input is shown as another label (I have a DATETIME type of that column in MySQL, so it always yields the correct time).

I read multiple articles about using `MouseListener`, `MouseEvent` etc and implemented those, but none gave a result (the new label just did not appear on the screen).

*Here is my output, don't mind the last value appearing at the end: I am still trying to get around that on my own:*
[image]

And here is my code:

```
public class ReviewBalance extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static JFrame frame; 

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //these are the positions where i am placing the coord axes
        int width = this.getWidth() / 10;
        int height = this.getHeight() / 10; 

        //these are the actual lines
        Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D) g; 

        g1.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g1.drawLine(0, 9 * height, 10 * width, 9 * height);
        g1.drawLine(width, 0, width, 10 * height); 

        //and this is supposed to be the graph
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
        g2.setColor(new Color(235, 142, 42));

        Polygon p = new Polygon();  

        int scale = 75; //this is the factor that determines how much you see from the graph
        int i = 1; //this is the pos where the first coord is placed

        double test = 0; 

        try {
            String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/logindb?serverTimezone=CET";
            String username = "root"; 
            String password = ""; 
            Class.forName(driver); 

            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            PreparedStatement statement1 = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `logindb`.`receipts_helper`"); 
            ResultSet data = statement1.executeQuery();  

            while(data.next()) { 

                p.addPoint(width + scale*i, (int) (this.getHeight() / 2 - data.getDouble("sum")));

                JLabel label = new JLabel(Double.toString(data.getDouble("sum")));
                label.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.ITALIC, 20));
                label.setBounds(width + scale*i, (int) (this.getHeight() / 2 - data.getDouble("sum")), 90, 25);
                label.setVisible(true);
                frame.getContentPane().add(label);

                i = i + 1; 

                test = data.getDouble("sum"); //this line is here for the last-value-issue

            }

            statement1.close();
            connect.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        g2.drawPolyline(p.xpoints, p.ypoints, p.npoints);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(Double.toString(test));
        label2.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.ITALIC, 20));
        label2.setBounds(width + scale*i, (int) (this.getHeight() / 2 - test), 90, 25);
        label2.setVisible(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        frame = new JFrame(); 
        frame.setSize(1000, 800);
        frame.setTitle("Review Balance");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        ReviewBalance reviewBalance = new ReviewBalance(); 

        frame.add(reviewBalance); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I have excluded those `MouseListener` parts, as there were so many implementations, I didn't know what to paste.

The question is: does anyone have a hint or piece of code for getting around this issue?

Comment: Generally, in Swing, if you have a drawing panel, like a graph, you don't add Swing components to the drawing panel.  You can draw the numbers on the graph, but you need to keep a logical model of the Rectangles where you drew the numbers, so you can handle mouse actions properly.

Comment: Further to the suggestion of @GilbertLeBlanc, also don't do **database access** from within a paint method! A paint method should neither change the GUI nor do any potentially time consuming operations. Also it should immediately call the super method. *"once the user hovers over a value, the time of input is shown as another label" * Consider using a `JToolTip`.

Comment: Thank you both! I used your tips and now it looks a lot better. Also i gave up on the paint method :)

Comment: *"Thank you both!"* Tip: Add @GilbertLeBlanc (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. (Limitation: Only one person can be notified per comment.)